# DATE_FORMAT() doesn't display anything in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml, rss, date-format

My code is...

```
 $getMe = "SELECT ID, NewsType, Content, DATE_FORMAT(DateTime,'%a, %e %b %Y %T') as formatted_date FROM tblnews ORDER BY DateTime DESC LIMIT 15";
    $articles = mysql_query($getMe) or die(mysql_error());  
    while ($article = mysql_fetch_array($articles)){  
     echo '<item>  
              <title>'.$article[NewsType].'</title>  
              <description><![CDATA['.$article[Content].']]></description>  
              <link>MySite.com</link>  
              <pubDate>'.$row[formatted_date].' GMT</pubDate>  
          </item>'; 
}
```

I tried to `echo $row[formatted_date]` but it doesn't display anything.

BTW, I am making this for an xml file :)

Comment: you need to use like this `echo $article['formatted_date']`

Comment: Stop using mysql_* functions its depricated now... Use mysqli_* OR PDO...

Answer (score 1):

I didnt see a variable `$row` in your code.Also you have to keep the keys of the array in quotes. Probably you need to do the following

```
$getMe = "SELECT ID, NewsType, Content,   
DATE_FORMAT(DateTime,'%a, %e %b %Y %T') as formatted_date   
FROM tblnews ORDER BY DateTime DESC LIMIT 15";


$articles = mysql_query($getMe) or die(mysql_error());  

while ($article = mysql_fetch_array($articles)){  

 echo '  
       <item>  
          <title>'.$article['NewsType'].'</title>  
          <description><![CDATA['.$article['Content'].']]></description>  
          <link>MySite.com</link>  
          <pubDate>'.$article['formatted_date'].' GMT</pubDate>  
      </item>';  

}
```

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't notice that one. Aside from this code, what else do I need to have it posted to social media sites? Would feedburner send this to twitterfeed or dlvr.it or whatever feeds whenever I post a new update?